# How to set a variable to SYSMIS in SPSS depending on an IF-Condition

Tags: spss

Lets say for example I have a variable in SPSS named *var1* containing ones and zeros. And I have another variable *var2* which I want to set to *sysmis* if *var1* = 1.

How can I do that in SPSS?

The line

```
IF (var1=1) var2 = SYSMIS.
```

produces an error.

Comment: This question used to bug me from time to time, so I decided to share it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to use the system variable `$SYSMIS`.

```
IF (var1=1) var2 = $SYSMIS.
```

$SYSMIS is documented in Variables section under Universals section in the Syntax Reference Guide.